# Why can't I pass a type member of a class as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am unable to pass a type member of a class as a template parameter.
For example in the following piece of code :

```
std::array<int, 1> a;
std::array<typename a::value_type, 1> a2;
```

won't compile.

What is the reason for this ? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does the compiler not give any message about the error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`a` is not a type, hence you can't apply `::` to it. You can use `decltype` to retrieve `a`'s type :

```
std::array<int, 1> a;
std::array<decltype(a)::value_type, 1> a2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quentin has given you one way to get around this. Here's two more.

The obvious solution, of course, is to replace the name of the object `a` with the name of its type:

```
std::array<typename std::array<int, 1>::value_type, 1> a2;
```

However, looking at your code, I wondered if what you wanted is to define *types*, rather than objects. I think `a` and `a2` make exceptionally bad type names (so my suspicion was likely wrong), but here you go:

```
typedef std::array<int, 1> a;
typedef std::array<typename a::value_type, 1> a2;
```

You can now create instances of those types.